# tar files including directory without siblings

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I have following file structure

```
.
├── doc1.pdf
├── doc2.pdf
└── images
    ├── img1.jpg
    └── img2.jpg
```

I would like to tar images directory preserving parent `images` (without full path to it). What is more i would like skip other documents in directory (doc1, doc2) Currently I use:

```
tar -cf /sth_dir/images.tar -C /images/ . --exclude="doc*"
```

but  i would like to not use `--exclude` because additional files, with different names might be added there.

Comment: your '-C images' already does the job, you don't have to --exclude anything. Given, that you stated the correct question ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
tar cf /sth_dir/images.tar images
```

`tar` produced this output when I included the `-v` argument (`tar cvf ...`):

```
a images
a images/img1.jpg
a images/img2.jpg
```

And the tar file contents looks like this:

```
images/
images/img1.jpg
images/img2.jpg
```

Comment: If you provide full path eg. `/home/jdoe/Desktop/test/images` then  it will be included in tar. I want have only images dir.

Comment: This tar command uses an absolute path only for the tar file itself.  The image files are still relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

```
tar cf /sth_dir/images.tar -C / images/images
```

Assuming that you have an `images` directory embedded in an other `images` directory.

man tar:

```
 -C, --directory DIR
       change to directory DIR
```

as an alternative, you can consider `cpio`. Assuming you are experienced with `find`, you can be very specific what would you like to archive. For example this duo gives you the possibility to archive a directory, without its content, which I found very useful in many use-cases.

Comment: And what if i do not want to change dir to `images` parent? Is there any way to do it with absolute paths?

Comment: that is what is up there, because the PWD is /, and the content of the tar file is images/images.

Comment: in other words, you can `tar cf tarfile.tar -C / images/a images/b`, which includes `images`, `images/a`, `images/b` without including `images/c`